# How to get purchase history using Anjlab getPurchaseHistory() method Android In App Billing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, in-app-purchase

I am new to Java and android development. I have a app and I need to purchase history using Anjlab library.
On git I found this page

https://github.com/anjlab/android-inapp-billing-v3

and it mentions the following:

```
BillingProcessor bps;
bps = BillingProcessor.newBillingProcessor(this, getResources().getString(R.string.play_console_license), this);


public List<BillingHistoryRecord> getPurchaseHistory(String type, Bundle extraParams)
```

I am unfamiliar on how to use

```
public List<BillingHistoryRecord> getPurchaseHistory(String type, Bundle extraParams)
```

and I am not entirely sure how to use it.

My goal is to print out the transaction history eg the token and orderid etc

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get the token you can do something like this:

```
        BillingProcessor bps;
        bps = BillingProcessor.newBillingProcessor(this, getResources().getString(R.string.play_console_license), this);
                bps.loadOwnedPurchasesFromGoogle();
                bps.getPurchaseListingDetails("yourproductcode");
                String token = Objects.requireNonNull(bps.getSubscriptionTransactionDetails("yourproductcode")).purchaseToken;
```

You may want to add to empty checks around this